# Splitview Orientation issue.(Portrait mode)

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, orientation, uisplitviewcontroller

**Background**

I have an iPad splitview application.The split view is the rootview controller for the window.I need a login screen for the app and hence I present it like so :`[self.splitViewController presentViewController:self.loginView animated:NO completion:nil];`.I have a popover on the master view anchored to the navigation bar `UIBarButtonItem` which aids the user to logout.This is working gr8.

**Problem**:

I need to support both orientations and so the master view has to be shown in the portrait mode as well.The first problem I faced is  when the user logs out of the application in portrait mode,the master view is not dismissed and the login view is presented when the master view is still visible.I managed to fix this by replicating the tap event on the left bar button like so:

```
[self.detailViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.target performSelector:self.detailViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.action];
```

This gives rise to a second problem.**When i logout the masterview is dismissed correctly by the above snippet and the loginview is seen.But now if i change my orientation to landscape and login again the master view is replace by a black strip (equal in width to masterview).I reckon that the splitview still thinks its in portarit view and the orientation changes are not propagated to the splitviewcontroller**.Can anyone please help me solve this problem.

**What I have done so far**:

I tried to explicitly call `-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` with the updated orientation on the detailview but it did not work.

I reset the rootview controller of the application to the same splitviewcontroller instance created in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` hoping that this might serve as a refresh but it did not heed.

I do not know from where to go from here.**Important note:I am on iOS 6.0**.Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i fixed it by changing the origin of the master view

```
- (void)showMasterView
{
    if (!self.masterIsVisible)
    {
        self.masterIsVisible = YES;
        NSArray *controllers = self.splitViewController.viewControllers;
        UIViewController *rootViewController = [controllers objectAtIndex:0];

        UIView *rootView = rootViewController.view;
        CGRect rootFrame = rootView.frame;
        rootFrame.origin.x += rootFrame.size.width;

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"showView" context:NULL];
        rootView.frame = rootFrame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

- (void)hideMasterView
{
    if (self.masterIsVisible)
    {
        self.masterIsVisible = NO;
        NSArray *controllers = self.splitViewController.viewControllers;
        UIViewController *rootViewController = [controllers objectAtIndex:0];

        UIView *rootView = rootViewController.view;
        CGRect rootFrame = rootView.frame;
        rootFrame.origin.x -= rootFrame.size.width;

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"hideView" context:NULL];
        rootView.frame = rootFrame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

This will only happen in the portrait mode.
[Thanks to...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352980/make-hide-unhide-master-view-controller-work-in-landscape-the-same-as-portrait).

PS: Sincere apologies for not posting this answer earlier. I had completely forgotten about it after the issue was resolved. Mending my mistake now  :)